# How to pass bytes object in Python to a C++ function wrapped with Swig?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a bytes variable in Python that I want to pass to a C++ function, and then want to return the bytes later on, also via a C++ function. The C++ code is wrapped in Swig. Does anyone know how I can do this or have a basic example? I have tried using void* as the type in C++, but I can't get it to work.

C++ example.hpp code:

```
class MyTestClass {
public:    
    void set_data(void* data);
    void* get_data();

private:
    void* data;
};
```

C++ example.cpp code:

```
void MyTestClass::set_data(void* data)
{
    this->data = data;
}

void* MyTestClass::get_data()
{
    return data;
}
```

Swig interface file:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example

%include <std_string.i>

%{
    #include "example.hpp"
%}

%include "example.hpp"
```

Test Python code:

```
from example import MyTestClass

test_class = MyTestClass()

data1 = b"test"
test_class.set_data(data1)

data2 = test_class.get_data()    
print(data2)
```

Compilation:

```
swig -c++ -python -modern -py3 example.i
export CC=g++
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    test_class.set_data(data_1)
  File "example.py", line 119, in set_data
    return _example.MyTestClass_set_data(self, data)
TypeError: in method 'MyTestClass_set_data', argument 2 of type 'void *'
```

Comment: Why `void*` instead of `char*`? That's what a `bytes` is under the covers, and also what the closest C equivalent to `bytes` is.

Comment: Ok I changed to char*, but now the returned data is a str and not bytes. How do I get bytes back?

Comment: Without seeing your C++, SWIG, and Python code—or, rather, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) all I can do is blind shotgun debugging, which isn't going to do anyone any good. Edit your question to contain enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, minimal example added, also with some string tests just before the data tests.

Comment: How much freedom do you have to change that design? You almost certainly want to add either a `PyObject*`, another `void*` or a `size_t` to help make everything pass in both directions and get the ownership right.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with %cstring_output_allocate_size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with a cstring.i template:

%cstring_output_allocate_size(char** data_out, int* maxdata, NULL)

When I set the data I also set the size, which I use to set maxdata. The third parameter is NULL and not free because the data is meant to be a reference only.

Answer (score 1):

You should use char* instead of void*.
In addition, you should not use the

```
%include <std_string.i>
```

in the example.i file, as that has the typemap definition converting char * to a string.

Minor issue: you example.cpp shall #include "example.hpp" to have a definition for MyTestCLass.

Comment: I tried changing void* to char* but get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    test_class.set_data(data_1)
  File "example.py", line 104, in set_data
    return _example.MyTestClass_set_data(self, data)
TypeError: in method 'MyTestClass_set_data', argument 2 of type 'char *'

Comment: Thanks, changing to char* was step 1, see my own answer for the second part, which was using the %cstring_output_allocate_size template.